# Junit: Unit Testing for big data natural language processing

Tags: junit, nlp

My problem is a tad vague but my question is specific.

**QUESTION**

Can anyone point me to well-informed documentation on how to unit test big data natural language processing systems?

**CONTEXT**

Big data processing systems are often multi-threaded and are also highly forgiving of Exception states. Very often Exceptions are caught and not thrown in order to allow for "messy" data.

However, in unit testing such systems, levels of stringency should be higher than in production conditions. This level of stringency allows developers to at least be aware of what kind of conditions throw exceptions.

The problem is that such systems absorb the exceptions, so junit tests won't pick them up. I am looking for a parsimonious design for unit testing in such circumstances. Don't want to re-invent the wheel. Hence looking for relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1):

No one should be able to point you to any "well-informed documentation on how to unit test big data natural language processing systems" because the well-informed opinion is that no special such documentation need exist. The reason is that your unit tests (even in big NLP systems) should all pass and run quickly if your functions are correct.

What I think you meant to ask is more to do with integration testing and actually running these systems on messy (test or production) data sets. Most of my integration tests run on fixed data sets, and I expect them to pass all the time unless there are network/database failures or other events beyond the control of my system.

For integration tests on ever-changing data sets or actually running on production you will have to look at the documentation of the underlying architecture/framework you are using. I use UIMA based architecture and you can explicitly set things like error rate thresholds - see below for an example copied from the UIMA Documentation. I am sure GATE, Deeplearning4Java or whatever else the cool kids are using these days has similar functionality but as far as I know it is framework specific.

```
<casProcessor deployment="integrated" name="Person">
  <descriptor>
    <include href="[descriptor]"/>
  </descriptor>
  <deploymentParameters/>
  <errorHandling>
    <errorRateThreshold action="terminate" value="100/1000"/>
    <maxConsecutiveRestarts action="terminate" value="30"/>
    <timeout max="100000"/>
  </errorHandling>
  <checkpoint batch="100" time="1000ms"/>
</casProcessor>
```